# Longest subgroup chain in $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups

What is the length $\ell$ of longest chain of subgroups
$$\{e\} \lneq H_1 \lneq \dotsc \lneq H_\ell = G$$
in  $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$?

Comment: A assume $p$ is meant to be prime. It's tempting to include the upper triangular and upper unipotent (=$p$-Sylow) subgroups in such a chain. This yields a chain of length $n(n-1)/2+(n-1)f(p-1)+1$, where $f(p-1)$ is the number of (possibly equal) prime factors of $p-1$ [thus $(n-1)f(p-1)$ is the maximal length of a chain of subgroups in the maximal torus $(\mathbf{F}_p^*)^{n-1}$].

Comment: Your sign to mean "proper subgroup of" looks like "less or equal but not equal"; I think $<$ is commonly used to mean this.

Comment: Well, what would you use that sign for otherwise? "$H<G$" is used by some to mean "subgroup" and by some to mean "proper subgroup".

Comment: I'd use $<$ and tell people using $<$ for "subgroup of" to be less lazy with using the backslash sign on their keyboard :)

Comment: Solomon Turull answer this question. From memory the answer is $\pi(B)+n-1$ where $B$ is a Borel, $\pi$ is the number of primes dividing its order.

Comment: (To see why this is a possible length: $B$ is solvable, so its subgroup length is obviously $\pi(B)$, and then the overgroups of $B$ are just a bunch of parabolics.) Solomon-Turull's answer holds for any group of Lie type I believe. I'll write this as an answer when I have a moment.

Comment: Sorry, just saw @YCor's comment: of course, you are spot on.

Comment: Ah, I've looked at Solomon-Turull (Chains of subgroups if groups of Lie type III) and I find that their main theorem is not quite as I remembered. It says: *For all primes p, there exist an integer $F$ such that if $G=G_r(p^m)$ is a quasisimple of Lie type and $m\geq F$, then $\ell(G)=\ell(B)+r$*. Here $\ell$ is the length of the longest subgroup chain. The requirement that $m\geq F$ means that the result does not apply here... It improves @YCor's upper bound -- the final 1 turns into an $n-1$ -- but it doesn't definitely state that this is as long as it can be...

Comment: ... However the first paper in the series asserts that the bound is optimal for $p=2$.

Comment: Ok indeed I wrote $+1$ but forgot all parabolics strictly between the upper triangular subgroup and the whole group; it should have been $+n-1$.

Answer (score 15):

We write $\ell(G)$ for the length of the longest subgroup chain of a group $G$. If $G$ is of Lie type, write $B$ for a Borel subgroup of $G$, and note that $\ell(B)$ is equal to the number of prime divisors of $|B|$ (since $B$ is solvable).

Let me explain the situation in the literature as I understand it. Unfortunately it will only yield a partial answer to the question. We start with this paper....

*Solomon, Ron; Turull, Alexandre*, [**Chains of subgroups in groups of Lie type. III**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s2-44.3.437), J. Lond. Math. Soc., II. Ser. 44, No. 3, 437-444 (1991). [ZBL0776.20007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0776.20007).

... whose main theorem is as follows:

**Theorem**: For all primes p, there exist an integer $F$ such that if $G=G_r(p^m)$ is a quasisimple of Lie type and $m\geq F$, then $\ell(G)=\ell(B)+r$.

Unfortunately, the requirement that $m\geq F$ means that the result does not apply here... However, one of the main theorems of this paper

*Solomon, Ron; Turull, Alexandre*, [**Chains of subgroups in groups of Lie type. I**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(90)90261-L), J. Algebra 132, No. 1, 174-184 (1990). [ZBL0714.20011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0714.20011).

implies the following

**Theorem**: Suppose that $G_r(2^m)$ is a quasisimple group of Lie type. Then $\ell(G)=\ell(B)+r$.

So that, at least, answers your question for $p=2$. For $p\neq 2$, the middle paper in the above series (which includes Seitz as an author) is the following:

*Seitz, Gary M.; Solomon, Ron; Turull, Alexandre*, [**Chains of subgroups in groups of Lie type. II**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s2-42.1.93), J. Lond. Math. Soc., II. Ser. 42, No. 1, 93-100 (1990). [ZBL0728.20018](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0728.20018).

Theorem B of that paper implies the following:

**Theorem**: Suppose that $K$ is a positive real number, $m$ a positive real number and $G_r$ any group scheme of Lie type. Then there exists $p$ a prime such that
$\ell(G)>\ell(B)+r+K$.

Thus the bound for $p=2$ fails "as badly as possible" for odd $p$. I've scanned this paper, and the way they show this theorem for $SL_n(p^m)$ is by looking at the normalizer, $N$, of a torus $T$.

**Edit**: I wrote earlier that  one should consider the normalizer of a maximal split torus to see why the latter theorem works. In actual fact one should use the normalizer of *non-split* torus to get a longer chain. So, for instance, if $n$ is odd and if $p^m+1$ has many more prime divisors than $p^m-1$, then one might look $N$, the normalizer of the torus $(p^{2m}-1)^d$ where $2d+1=n$. One can see that
$$\ell(N) = d\pi(p^{2m}-1) + \ell(S_d),$$
which, depending on $p$ and $n$, will get you a longer chain. To calculate precisely how long a chain you obtain you can use the fact that $\ell(S_n)=\lfloor{\frac{3n-1}{2}}\rfloor - b_n$, where $b_n$ is the number ones in the base $2$ expansion of $n$, by a theorem here:

*Cameron, Peter J.; Solomon, Ron; Turull, Alexandre*, [**Chains of subgroups in symmetric groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(89)90256-1), J. Algebra 127, No. 2, 340-352 (1989). [ZBL0683.20004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0683.20004).

**Speculation**: Let me conjecture what might be the actual answer to your question. It's easier to work inside $GL_n(p)$ rather than $SL_n(p)$. It seems to me that one can do even better than torus normalizers, by looking at Levi subgroups. Consider a Levi subgroup,
$$L=GL_{d_1}(p^{i_1}) \times \cdots \times GL_{d_k}(p^{i_k}),$$
where $\sum d_j i_j=n$. By taking the Borel subgroup of this, one can obtain a subgroup chain in $L$ of length
$$ f(L)= n-k + \sum\limits_{j=1}^k \left( d_i\pi(p^{i_j}-1) + \frac12d_j(d_j+1)\right).$$
This would then yield a subgroup chain in $G$ of length something like $g(L)=f(L)+k-1+\frac12\left(n^2-\sum_{i=1}^k d_i^2\right)$ (I think). Now $\ell(G)$ would be the maximum of all such values (so maximise over $L$, where we think of $L$ as a partition of the integer $n$).

Comment: Nice job! I'd still like to get a complete answer (though the above does not seem to be far from one).